# Why am I getting "no such file or directory" for an opencv file that exists when compiling in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use the OpenCV library in C++ (VSCode), so I have the statement `#include <opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`. When I try to compile using gcc in Ubuntu, however, I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:48:10: fatal error: opencv2/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and Ubuntu in general so I have no idea why this is happening, as I double checked and the file absolutely exists. In fact, even though it's apparently skipped the `imgproc` folder in finding the file, `imgproc.hpp` exists both in `opencv2` and in the folder `imgproc` inside `opencv2` anyway. How do I get this to work?

Comment: What's the cmd-line you tried to use to build it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using #include "opencv4/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" instead?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried that and got the same error message as before.